# Get Excel of SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, excel, flow

I have a SharePoint DocLib. It contains an Excel spreadsheet I want to send every day at a specific time. Sending a mail every day... is not the problem.

To get this done I'm using Flow to build an automated "workflow". I achieved to receive single worksheets but not whole .xlsx files. The possibility to open SharePoint for single external people is not in my hand. So this option is not working I guess.

How can I get a copy of a specific file in a SharePoint document library?

Thanks for answers or related topics here (I've found none)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Get file content" function in Flow, 
and in the next step you can send it in attachment of a mail.

Comment: That's it, now I've got the xlsx as desired. It's not that easy to find the right option in the list. This one was quite at the bottom. The rest is very easy.